# Jmeter: How to bulk check/uncheck "Generate parent sample"

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

You create and test your script locally in jmeter, so that later you can upload it to blazemeter to run.

The test contains hundreds of transaction controllers, each representing a page, and created by the script recorder.

The problem is, to run it locally, and get transaction controller summary by page, not by every request, you have to check "generate parent sample".

but this has to be disabled when you upload to blaze.

How do people handle this?

It doesn't seem possible to bulk edit these or use a variable, every transaction controller (representing a page) has to be manually edited every time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter [.jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML files](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) so you can open your script with text/XML editor of your choice, look for the next line:

   ```
   <boolProp name="TransactionController.parent">false</boolProp>
   ```

   it means that the Transaction Controller doesn't generate the parent sample. If you replace it with:

   ```
   <boolProp name="TransactionController.parent">true</boolProp>
   ```

   it will generate the parent sample (and vice versa)
2. You can use [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/) tool which has capability of bulk changing arbitrary JMeter test element property to the desired value, in your case disabling "parent" mode of the Transaction Controller would be something like:

   ```
   execution:
     scenario:
       script: test.jmx
       modifications:
         set-prop:
           "Transaction Controller>TransactionController.parent": false
   ```